# What techniques are used to handle different timezone during OLAP calculation?

Tags: bigdata, business-intelligence, olap

I am reading a book about data warehouse. It tells that if I have a datetime data, I should store it as separate columns: year, month, date and raw datetime in millis. It is need for aggregation purposes (see also **updated** section) - for aggregation by date, month etc.  But what if I need aggregation for different timezones? Yes, it is possible to show UTC + timezone on UI, but what if business want to see aggregation on "shifted" day periods not see that day starts at 00:00+07?

**Note**

It is possible to calculate every time aggregation (year, month, day) for every timezone, but it takes too many calculations (as I understand).
Maybe there is a better way? Or every calculation for every timezone is a common solution?

**Updated**

About aggregation. By aggreagetion I mean, that there is a some process running on schedule (it run first time on all data and then on schedule for new comming only). So the process, when it "see" new data it calculates aggregation for all columns. For example, suppose that data is cutomer order, it has cost, user id and date. So process grab row with 1 cutomer order and "add" this information in several OLAP cube cells: day, month and year. Suppose that customer make an order with `$1` on `22.06.2015`. This order data (often cost) is "added" on following OLAP cells: `22` day, `06` month and `2015`. I am not qualified OLAP designer and cell may be different (for example it can be add to `22.06` instead of `22`), but the idea is to put data into separate cells for query optimization purposes, e.g. it much faster to select sum of cost from one cube cell `22.06.2015` instead of run calculation of all orders on `22.06.2015`. But in this case design day start on UTC, what if I need to start with different timezones? With such approach data aggregation increased by 24 times. :(

Storing date in UTC and show it on UI with offset is a common practice, but not in OLAP design when I need precalculation.

Comment: Please make a comment when downvoting.

Comment: I guess you just don't do it in database but in the tool you use to generate the results in form of report or however you want/need to display the data. If the timezone is important for you, then use a field to store the timezone as well.

Comment: Again: use another field to store the relevant timezone for that date. When the client consumes the data, in **that moment** you will operate on the timezone. But seriously, I cannot see the difference between seeing how much money the company earns at a timezone or another and use it as part of the relevant data of the report. What I found really useful is the proper hour I could use to make business oriented decisions.

Comment: It is assumed that timezone is stored in separate field, but what about precalculation? What if client request calculation is too long? So I need to store some intermediate result in data base and calculated it before user asks me about data.

Comment: You should not aggregate that kind of data while users generate the reports, the data should be inserted/updated on certain times in the day/week. That's business intelligence 101.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81147/discussion-between-cherry-and-luiggi-mendoza).

Answer (score 0):

But first of all, define your  "warehouse grain" on the level which will make other aggregations/calculations easier to make and maintenance.

In my opinion you should "handle & map" this business requirements on data-warehouse and ETL level. Yes keep each date level on separate columns, you will be able to make aggregations "easy & simple". Do not worry to add another level like your "24h aggregation". OLAP are build for that approach.

If you want to avoid extra aggregations, than create dedicated datamart. Your fact table will be a [accumulating snapshot](http://blog.oaktonsoftware.com/2012/01/when-do-you-need-accumulating-snapshot.html), instead  of transaction fact. Next created Dim "UTC" to handle your requirements. You will move aggregation effort from OLAP level to ETL level.

Hope this help.